# Problem: I can't display values i want from my queries and database in a component on Laravel Livewire

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I'm still new on Laravel and I'm still working on this project now:
So basically I have a table Recipes containing recipes with a name and vegetabes, a pivot table Recipes_vegetables and a table vegetables.
What i want is a search input that is gonna give me the values of my different tables that fit the input.
So this is my code:

Search.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Vegetable;
use App\Models\Recipe;

class Search extends Component
{
    public $query = '';

    public $vegetables;
    public $recipes;

    public function updatedQuery() 
    {
        $this->vegetables = Vegetable::where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->query.'%')
                            ->with('recipes')
                            ->get();

        $this->recipes = Recipe::where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->query.'%')
                            ->with('vegetables')
                            ->get();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.search');
    }
}
```

search.blade.php :

```
<div class="searchcomponent">
  <h1>Search</h1>
  <input wire:model="query" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  @if(!empty($query))
    <ul>
      @if(!empty($recipes))
        <div class="vegetables">
          @foreach($vegetables as $vegetable)
           
              <li><span class="material-icons">lunch_dining</span>{{ $vegetable->name }}</li>
            
          @endforeach
        </div>
      @else
        <li>No result</li>
      @endif
      <div class="recipes">
        @foreach($recipes as $recipe)
          @foreach($recipe->vegetables as $vegetable)
            <li><span class="material-icons">menu_book</span>{{ $recipe->name }}<span class="ingredient">Ingredient: {{ $vegetable->name }}</span></li>
          @endforeach
        @endforeach
      </div>
    </ul>
  @endif
</div>
```

Recipe.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Recipe extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function vegetables(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Vegetable::class, 'vegetables_recipes', 'recipe_id', 'vegetable_id');
    }

}
```

Vegetable.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vegetable extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function recipes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Recipe::class, 'vegetables_recipes', 'vegetable_id', 'recipe_id');
    }

}
```

**So basically this is what i get right now:**

**1st case**: I'm typing a vegetable's name in the input:

What I **should** have :

Get every vegetable's name that fits the input AND get every recipe's name that fits the input AND get every recipe that has a vegetable 's name that fits the input
**Exemple:** I have a fish and chips recipe that has 'Potatoes' as an ingredient linked with the pivot table. If i type 'Po' I should have on my render:

- Potato
- Fish and chips (because the recipe is made with potatoes)

What I **actually** have right now:

If i type 'po': I'm only getting the results that have 'Po' in their name, so i'm getting Potato, but i'm not getting Fish and chips. If i type Fish tho, i'm getting Fish and chips.

**2nd case:**:I'm typing a recipe's name in the input.

What I **should** have:

Get every recipe's name that fits the input AND get every vegetable's name that fits the input AND every vegetable that is needed for a recipe that fits the input.
**Exemple:** I have in my vegetables table : Egg, sugar, chocolate. My recipe table has a 'cake'
and with the pivot table i linked the cake with my egg my chocolate and my sugar. Now if i type 'cake' in my input i should have in the first div 'vegetables':

- Sugar
- Chocolate
- Egg

And in my second div I should have 3 entries:

- Cake, ingredient : Sugar
- Cake, ingredient : Egg
- Cake, ingredient : Chocolate

What I **actually** have :

All the second part, but I'm not getting any entry in my vegetable div....

Any idea how to solve those 2 problems ? Don’t hesitate to ask for any clarification or precision

Answer (score 1):

First problem:

You get the $recipes by name so if you type "Potato" it's going to check if any recipes have "Potato" in it's name and this is going to be `false` for the "Potato". why do you have any result in your page is because you use `empty($recipes)` which beside the time you load the page is always going to return `true`. so you need to replace it with `$recipes->isEmpty()`.

you want the vegetable records to be shown on the page and then for each of them  want to see the recipes. so you should get the recipes from vegetable like `$vegetable->recipes` and loop through them. and you should not go through vegetables based on the `$recipes` being empty.

Second problem:

Again you get the $vegetables by name so if you type "Cake" it's going to check if any vegetables have "Cake" in it's name and this is going to be `false` for the "Cake".

Comment: Thanks for your answer !!
I've tried to change my code with the elements you added but it still doesn't seem to work, maybe i did it wrong but could you tell me what to change precisely if you have time ?
Thanks